# Making tar split archives as it compresses?

Tags: tar, compression

I want to compress a file with `tar` but I'd like to know if its possible to do it while splitting the files.

I know that in windows is possible to do this with winrar, I also know I can use `split` but I would then have to unsplit this from Linux

Comment: On a different note, it is kind of incorrect to say 'compressing' with `tar`. Tar does not compress file, it only archives the directory as a single file. It compresses only when `-z` option is used.

Answer (score 3):

You can send the output of `tar` to stdout and then pipe this into the `split` program.

```
tar cvzf - ./path/to/dir | split --suffix-length=LENGTH --bytes=SIZE - chunkedTar
```

Choose your suffix length and File sizes `man split`

To un-split, concatenate the files in the correct order and pipe that into `tar`.

```
cd where_you_want_to_untar
cat /path_to_chunks/chunkedTar* | tar xvzf -
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it appears that files split under Linux with `split` are able to be reassembled in Windows using `copy`.

See the related question and answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1121070/revisions)